# Plug and Play WiFi cards for a whole bunch of distros

Tags: wireless, compatibility, pcie

I need a plug and play WiFi card for the following. If you know of a WiFi card model that is plug and play compatible with at least a few of these, please list it.

Debian,
Ubuntu,
Linux Mint,
Kali Linux,
Arch,
Manjaro,

Comment: What kind of wifi card? USB? PCI? Built in?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

When in doubt; Try buying something from Intel. The reason is because they have an extremely good track record with the Linux Kernel Team, as is often mentioned by lead kernel developers. So good in fact, that there are drivers for intel chips already developed for the Linux Kernel, that never made it to market.

So any Intel Chip and you should be good, although in general today, most wireless cards work for linux anyways.

Comment: Akiva I need a PCIe, preferably not 16 pin because I'd like to run dual graphics cards when I get the money, but if its necessary, that's fine. I'll look into Intel. Thanks for the help.

Comment: If the answer was acceptable, would you mind upvoting it, and accepting it as an answer? The reason why I ask is that it helps keep the stack exchange clean, by making sure administrators know which questions have been answered. Good luck!

Comment: I can't vote it up because I don't have 15 reputation. I think I set it as the chosen answer though.